# Date to Day of Week in Groovy

Tags: date, groovy

I have variables that are formatted like the following example:

```
2011-03-07
```

and from them I want to output the day of the week. For example:

```
Monday
```

or even just

```
Mon
```

I am working in Groovy, any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `Date.parse` to turn the string into a date, and then index it with `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` to get the specific day.  Example:

```
assert Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2011-03-07")[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] == Calendar.MONDAY
```

If you want the day as a string, try the `Date.format` method.  The exact output depends on your locale:

```
assert Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2011-03-07").format("EEE") == "Mon"
assert Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2011-03-07").format("EEEE") == "Monday"
```

See the documentation for [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more information on the formatting strings.

If you want the day formatted for a specific locale, you'll have to create a SimpleDateFormat object and pass in a locale object.

```
fmt = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE", new Locale("fr"))
assert fmt.format(Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2011-03-07")) == "lun."
fmt = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", new Locale("fr"))
assert fmt.format(Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2011-03-07")) == "lundi"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new SimpleDateFormat('E').format Date.parse("10-jan-2010")
```

neater for me

Answer (score 0):

```
new SimpleDateFormat('E').format new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse('2011-03-07')
```